# Can some one pls help me the below function is returning with junk character

Tags: c

```
char   WSOH_SO_ID[11]; --> value is 3723611
char* FPART_SO_ID = "";
FPART_SO_ID = substr(WSOH_SO_ID, 0, 5);

char* substr(const char *src, int m, int n)
{
    // get length of the destination string
    int len = n - m;

    // allocate (len + 1) chars for destination (+1 for extra null character)
    char *dest = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (len + 1));

    // start with m'th char and copy 'len' chars into destination 
    strncpy(dest, (src + m), len);

    // return the destination string
    return dest;
}
```

Comment: Please at least format your code properly, and add description on your expected result, as well as how the current behavior is wrong.

Comment: what do you mean the value of `WSOH_SO_ID` is 3723611? it's a character array, your listed value is an integer

Comment: If you mean the string `"3723611"` you should show the value in quotes. Otherwise it is an integer value which cannot be correct.

Answer (score 2):

```
strncpy(dest, (src + m), len);
```

You will have to explicitly terminate the `dest`.

Read::

> The strncpy() function is similar, except that at most n bytes of src
> are copied. **Warning: If there is no null byte among the first n bytes
> of src, the string placed in dest will not be null-terminated**.